# How to use Multiple And operator in the if statement in modelica?

Tags: if-statement, operator-keyword, modelica, dymola

I'm coding the LMTD method in the heat transfer and met some errors when using the and operators more than two times simultaneously.

```
if (del_T1 > beta) and (del_T2 > beta) and (del_T1<>del_T2) then
    T_LMTD = (del_T1-del_T2) / ( (log(del_T1)) - (log(del_T2)));
  elseif (del_T1 > beta) and (del_T2 > beta) and (del_T1==del_T2) then
    T_LMTD = (del_T1-del_T2) / 2;
  elseif (del_T1 > beta) and (del_T2 < beta) then
    T_LMTD = (del_T1 - beta) / ( (log(del_T1/beta)) * (1 - zeta * (del_T2 - beta)));
  elseif (del_T1 < beta) and (del_T2 > beta) then
    T_LMTD = (del_T2 - beta) / ( (log(del_T2/beta)) * (1 - zeta * (del_T1 - beta)));
  elseif (del_T1 < beta) and (del_T2 < beta) then
    T_LMTD = beta / ( (1 - zeta * (del_T1 - beta))  * (1 - zeta * (del_T2 - beta)));
  else
    T_LMTD = beta / ( (1 - zeta * (del_T1 - beta))  * (1 - zeta * (del_T2 - beta)));
  end if;
```

Unfortunately, the error messages are printed like below when i simulate the model only when i used the And operators more than two times in one line.

[image]

How can i use And operator in multiple times? or Because of other problems?

Comment: 'And' can of course be used multiple times. But with this code it's hard to help. Can you provide a full working minimal example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem isn't the and-operator but the equality-operators, `del_T1<>del_T2` and `del_T1==del_T2`.

If you had removed the and-parts they would have generated the error message "Non-real equation in continuous time are not legal:".

And if you managed to generate code it would have given the more accurate error message:
  Variables of type Real cannot be compared for equality.

Which is stated in section 3.5 of the Modelica specification, https://specification.modelica.org/v3.4/Ch3.html#equality-relational-and-logical-operators

A work-around for that is to replace it by "close enough"; e.g. replace `del_T1==del_T2` by `abs(del_T1-del_T2)<tol`, for some tolerance tol.

That gives a working example as:

```
  Real T_LMTD;
  input Real del_T1;
  input Real del_T2;
  input Real zeta;
  parameter Real beta=0.7;
  parameter Real tol=1e-6;
equation 
 if (del_T1 > beta) and (del_T2 > beta) and abs(del_T1-del_T2)>tol then
    T_LMTD = (del_T1-del_T2) / ( (log(del_T1)) - (log(del_T2)));
  elseif (del_T1 > beta) and (del_T2 > beta) and abs(del_T1-del_T2)<tol then
    T_LMTD = (del_T1-del_T2) / 2;
  elseif (del_T1 > beta) and (del_T2 < beta) then
    T_LMTD = (del_T1 - beta) / ( (log(del_T1/beta)) * (1 - zeta * (del_T2 - beta)));
  elseif (del_T1 < beta) and (del_T2 > beta) then
    T_LMTD = (del_T2 - beta) / ( (log(del_T2/beta)) * (1 - zeta * (del_T1 - beta)));
  elseif (del_T1 < beta) and (del_T2 < beta) then
    T_LMTD = beta / ( (1 - zeta * (del_T1 - beta))  * (1 - zeta * (del_T2 - beta)));
  else
    T_LMTD = beta / ( (1 - zeta * (del_T1 - beta))  * (1 - zeta * (del_T2 - beta)));
  end if;
```

(Obviously the variable declarations can be changed.)